# Recuperar valor traído desde un api y mostrado en componente

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un componente básico en React, que me trae una lista de valores *{id, nombre, identificador}* desde un api y los muestra en un componente haciendo un mapeo básico de todos los elementos y mostrándolos de la siguiente manera.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como requisito, necesito que el campo nombre se pueda actualizar, por eso al traerlo desde el api lo pinto directamente en un *input* para que se pueda editar, estoy buscando la manera que al presionar el botón de actualizar me tome el *{id, nombre}* de la tarjera correspondiente. En este momento lo que pasa es que si doy actualizar en la primera tarjeta, me muestra correctamente **T-Beam 1**, pero al presionar actualizar sobre la segunda tarjeta, vuelve a mostrar **T-Beam 1**.

**Componente encargado de traer los datos y realizar el mapeo**

```
export default class Equipos extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            scanner: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers.append('Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
        headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            cache: 'default'
        }

        fetch('http//:www.prueba.com', options
        ).then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ scanner: data })
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }


    render() {
        const scanner = this.state.scanner;
        return (
            <div className="movimientosList">
                {scanner.map(scan => {
                    return (
                        <ScannerItem key={scan.id} scan={scan} />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Componente donde se muestran los datos en tarjeras**

```
class ScannerItem extends Component {

    handleClik(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value
        alert(nombre);
    }
  
    render() {
        const {nombre, identificador} = this.props.scan;
        return (
            <div className="movimientosList-item" >
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <div className="media">
                            <div className="media-content">
                                <form>
                                    <p>
                                        <label>Nombre</label>
                                        <input 
                                            id='nombre'
                                            name = 'apinombre'
                                            value={nombre}
                                            />
                                    </p>
                                </form>
                                <button onClick={this.handleClik}>Actualizar</button>
                                <br></br>
                                <center><p ><strong>Identificador : </strong> {identificador}</p></center>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Estoy tratando de obtener los elementos diferenciados de cada tarjeta para poder actualizar el *nombre*.

Comment: Tu error esta en esta línea `const nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value` ya que estas dibujando los elementos del DOM mediante un ciclo (`map`) y el id de cada elemento es el mismo siempre (*nombre*). Lo que puedes hacer es concatenar el nombre con tu identificador para que cada elemento tenga distinto id :D

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera deberias considerar agregar tu comentario a una respuesta.